# Sonata Admin v2.3 - Order by on multiple columns with sortable = false

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by, sonata-admin

I have been using [this][1] solution to `ORDER BY` on multiple columns for version `2.2.*` It has been working well for almost a year.

Recently upgraded to version `2.3.*` and the list was not ordering the results any more.

I notice that if I set at least one column to be `sortable` things go back to normal. In my case I set all columns to `'sortable' => false` yet I still want to see things in a specific order; I just don't want users to select the sorting order!

Any way to get this working again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the following addition in the new [version](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/commit/d421f0f2ebd7b6281296435fb7083e4559168823#diff-409a051b11d25b4355f7ce9ca60eabd5); the `orderBy` options are removed if `ProxyQuery::getSortOrder()` doesn't return anything.

In this case the method is automatically called by the `Datagrid::buildPager()` IF AND ONLY IF the list configuration has at least one column set to `'sortable' => true`, see [DataGrid.php#L126](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.3/Datagrid/Datagrid.php#L126). If all columns are not sortable the custom `ORDER BY` options will be removed!

The only way to `ORDER BY`on multiple columns would be to ensure that the method `ProxyQuery::setSortOrder` is called at some point see [ProxyQuery.php#140](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/blob/master/Datagrid/ProxyQuery.php#L140).

I'm not sure if this is an unintended side-effect or it is how it was design to work.

To work around this either set at least one column to `'sortable' => true` (or don't set sortable at all) or modify the `createQuery` method in your admin class like so:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $proxyQuery = parent::createQuery($context);
    // Default Alias is "o"
    $proxyQuery->orderBy('o.name', 'ASC');
    // This can only be used for a single column. 
    $proxyQuery->setSortBy([], ['fieldName' => 'date']);
    $proxyQuery->setSortOrder('DESC');

    return $proxyQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sonata admin version 2.3 this simple solution works with or without sortable column:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $proxyQuery = parent::createQuery($context);

    $proxyQuery->orderBy('o.root', 'ASC');
    $proxyQuery->addOrderBy('o.lft', 'ASC');

    return $proxyQuery;
}
```